# setting up zf command line tool on shared hosting

Tags: php, zend-framework, shared-hosting

I am trying to install the zend command line tool zf on my shared hosting, but was not able to find a useful complete step by step guide. I also went through the Zend A Beginners Guide and there is little info about how one can set up the command line tool. If some one can list down the steps or and particular site which has the info would be great help to me.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Use the CLT for local development and upload all the source-codes to your shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Share host do not provide shell (bash) access so you cannot use CLI directly . Either you upgrade to VPS or dedicated server or do it locally and upload .